# PDO fetch as multidimensional array/object

Tags: arrays, pdo, multidimensional-array

I have a mysql database which looks like this

```
    G4  G3  G2 Libuser
    1   a   1   1
    1   a   2   2
    1   b   1   3
    2   c   1   4
    2   c   1   5
    2   c   2   6
    3   d   1   7
    3   e   1   8
    3   e   2   9
    3   e   3   10
    …   …   …   …
```

The database is grouped and sorted by G4, G3, G2 and Libuser

I'm trying to display this data with an HTML table structure like this :

```
G4 = 1
     G3 = a
          G2 = 1
              Libuser = 1
          G2 = 2
              Libuser = 2
     G3 = b
          G2 = 1
              Libuser = 3
G4 = 2
etc…
```

So I'm trying to fetch data as an associative multidimensional array and then It will be easier to print data with a loop through the array.

Is there an option with PDO to fetch data like that ? I tried with PDO_FETCH_ASSOC and PDO_FETCH_GROUP but it doesn't seem to work with multiple column groups. How can I perform this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and create a function to arrange the result array
the way you want

```
<?php
function customArrange($col1, $col2) {
    return array($col1 => $col2);
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT G4, G3 FROM youTable");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, "customArrange");
var_dump($result);
?>
```

or something like that